# Manually add ":animated" selector to jQuery objects

Tags: jquery

I have a function that animates dom elements with CSS3 if available. Now i often use the `:animeted` jQuery selector. How do i make my CSS3 Animated elements respond to `:animeted` selector also?

When a DOM Object is animated with jQuery it gets `"fxqueue":"inprogress"` in the Data object, so i was thinking i could manually add my elements using:

`$("div").eq(0).data({"fxqueue": "inprogress"});`

but

`console.log( $("div:animated") )`

does not select anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work.
The `:animated` filter is defined as

```
jQuery.expr.filters.animated = function( elem ) {
    return jQuery.grep(jQuery.timers, function( fn ) {
        return elem === fn.elem;
    }).length;
};
```

It checks whether the element is in `jQuery.timers`.

Instead, you can replace the `:animated` selector:

```
var originalAnimated = jQuery.expr.filters.animated;
jQuery.expr.filters.animated = function(elem) { 
    return originalAnimated(elem) || something;
};
```

Comment: well thank you! But i think i don't get everything. What would "something" (in your example) do if lets say if i had set .data("css3animate", true) on the elements that are animated by my function? ( http://jsfiddle.net/backflip/BqFsM/ )

Comment: @meo: `something` would be any condition.  You might write `|| $.data(elem, 'css3animate')`.

Comment: @SLaks: ok i have implemented it but as you can see it still gives the element back when its not animated anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/WsR5s/ (i removed css3animeted on from the data)

Comment: Change it to `!!($.data(elem, 'css3animated'))`; apparently, you need to coerce to a boolean.  http://jsfiddle.net/WsR5s/4/